# Writing a program which exchanges the letters "e" and "o" in one string using the `replace` method

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

For example, if I have `Hello World` it should become `Holle Werld`. How can I do this using `String.replace`? I've tried doing `"Hello World".replace("e","o")` but I only get `Hollo World` and if I use it again I will get `Helle Werld`.

Comment: Find a character not in the string, e.g. `z`. Replace e with z. Then think about how to proceed.

Comment: Don't use replace(). It's not the appropriate tool for the job.

Comment: Do you _have_ to use replace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also do:

```
String result = Arrays.stream(input.split(""))
                      .map(c -> c.equals("e") ? "o" : c.equals("o") ? "e" : c)
                      .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: Given the requirement to use `replace`, you could replace `"o"` with `c.replace("e", "o")`.

Comment: Take into account that this solution is not optimized. It calls method `String.split` while the string can be easily converted into `char[]`. Moreover it compares the `Strings` instead of lightweight comparison of primitive chars. In theory the strings may be very long.

Comment: probably better use `input.chars()` instead of splitting the string; but that is Java 9+

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Nope. Actually `input.chars()` is available `@since 1.8`. See my solution in a separate post.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Please consult https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html before commenting. You may be surprised, but `String` implements `CharSequence`.

Comment: OK, I stay corrected.... but doc of String is missing that, or wrong(?)

Comment: It's a *default* method of `java.lang.CharSequence`. So it is not reflected in documentation of `java.lang.String`.

Comment: The question specifically stated `replace` needed to be used. It sounds like a homework question. This answer fails to meet the question requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Optimized Java 8 solution:

```
String str = "Hello World!";

String result = str.codePoints()
                   .map(c -> c == 'e' ? 'o' : c == 'o' ? 'e' : c)
                   .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
                   .toString();
```

This solution avoids using highweight methods like `String.replace`, `String.split` and even `String.equals`.

Comment: You should use `codePoints()` instead of `chars()`.

Comment: You're right. However `chars()` works correctly in this example, we should use `codePoints()` for processing Unicode characters .

Answer (score 2):

I might treat the string as a character array here, and iterate over it:

```
String input = "Hello World";
char[] letters = input.toCharArray();
for (int i=0; i < letters.length; ++i) {
    if (letters[i] == 'e') {
        letters[i] = 'o';
    }
    else if (letters[i] == 'o') {
        letters[i] = 'e';
    }
}

String output = new String(letters);
System.out.println(input);
System.out.println(output);

Hello World
Holle Werld
```

Note that we could try doing a `String#replace` here, using a dummy character as a placeholder.  But that runs the risk of the placeholder appearing somewhere as part of the string.  The above solution would work in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

Following a suggestion by @Carlos Heuberger, you can use `'\uFFFF'` as a placeholder to interchange the characters with each other using the `String.replace()` method.. `'\uFFFF'` is considered a non-character in Unicode (i.e., it cannot appear in a String).

```
 String str = "Hello World";
 str = str.replace('o', '\uFFFF').replace('e', 'o').replace('\uFFFF', 'e');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The general problem with this solution is that it assumes the `#` character (or whatever other one you choose), does not appears anywhere else in the string, and that this would always be the case.

Comment: could use `'\uFFFF'`  (or `(char)-1`) that is considered a non-character in Unicode (proposed as sentinentel)

Comment: That's right @CarlosHeuberger. Thanks for the tip. Will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have to use `replace()`
Following is one way to do it:

```
String input = "Hello World";
input = input.replace("e","~");
input = input.replace("o","e");
input =input.replace("~","o);
```

Note: This assumes String won't have `"~"` in it. This code isn't robust enough code to handle that scenario.

Comment: This code doesn't do anything useful, owing to strings' immutability.

Comment: Thanks @Andy , fixed

Comment: There's a missing end quote, but I can't edit since not enough characters

Answer (score 0):

You can also find a character or a combination of characters that are not contained in your string, and use it as a temporary string of replacement. Here is an example :

```
private void funnyReplace2(String myString){
    String unused = findUnused(myString);
    System.out.println("Unused character(s) used : "+unused);
    myString=myString.replace("e",unused);
    myString=myString.replace("o","e");
    myString=myString.replace(unused,"o");

    System.out.println(myString);

}

private String findUnused(String aString){
    String lookingForChar = "@#{}]@$^£¨*ù%µ§/.?,;:!&é()-èïô";
    int looper = 0;
    while(looper<lookingForChar.length()){
        looper++;
        for (int i =0; i<=lookingForChar.length()-looper; i++){
            if (!aString.contains(lookingForChar.substring(i,i+looper)))
                return lookingForChar.substring(i,i+looper);
        }
    }
    return "What kind of String do you have ??";
}
```